# What is the plural of Prius?

Tags: grammatical-number, latin, business-language

[What would be the correct plural of *Prius*](http://www.youtube.com/user/ToyotaUSA?x=1prius), and why?

> A Latin professor would say Prium’s the best...

Comment: I would say Priuses.

Comment: Horrible little *ecno-boxen?*

Comment: In truth they are not bad little cars (and rather bigger on the inside than the outside.), but I couldn't resist.

Comment: The plural of virus is (incorrectly) said to be virii, so following that pattern plural of prius would be prii. ;)

Comment: @Guffa - no, following *that* accursed pattern, the plural would be "Priii"!

Comment: [Chris Smith surmises](http://twitter.com/#!/cswriter/status/24905349114892288), "internally at Toyota it's *profits*."

Comment: I kinda do hate you for asking this. I answered anyway.

Comment: Reminds me of a lecture I once attended where the speaker was discussing irregular plurals. He commented that it was ambiguous whether the plural for a Sony Walkman should be "Walkmen" or "Walkmans". So he contacted Sony and asked, and they replied that the proper declension was "one Sony Walkman, two Sony personal audio player devices".

Comment: @Jay You mean the proper inflection (or inflexion), not declension. It’s not like they’re telling you whether it’s a 1st declension vs 2nd declension vs 3rd declension vs the 4th declension vs the 5th declension.   And I really hate the 3rd declension; just had to get that in. :) I wish the damned Romans had stopped at just 2 declensions, but even Ancient Greek went to 3, and by the 3rd declension, we’re already sunk.

Comment: @tchrist Sure. I can see having three, one each for masculine, feminine, and neuter. It would surely be simpler to just have one, though arguably there's some value to having the gender information. Why do we need more than one conjugation? As far as I know it conveys no information. Ah well, I don't suppose it's as if someone sat down and said, "I'm going to invent a new language today. How will the grammar work?" Except for Esperanto and Klingon, of course.

Comment: @Jay Except that gender is completely orthogonal to declension in Latin nouns. You can have a 1st-declension masculine noun like *poeta* competing with the more common feminines in that declension like *amica*, or a 2nd-declension neuter like *vulgus* (well, sometimes neuter at least; some writers used it as a masculine) or a 2nd-declension feminine like *humus* competing with the more common masculines like *amicus* or neuters like *datum* of the 2nd declension. You simply have to learn a Latin noun’s declension and gender completely separately, and the ending won’t necessarily tell you that.

Comment: Well, MOST 1st declension nouns are feminine, MOST 2nd declension are masculine, and MOST 3rd declension are neuter. It's not "completely orthogonal", it's just "somewhat orthogonal". I think it's easier to learn the general rule and the small number of exceptions than to try to learn each individually. Besides, I don't find poeta that jarring as I think of poets as kind of effeminate anyway. :-) But agricola seems totally out of place: doesn't a farmer have to be pretty tough? Especially back then before all the labor-saving devices.

Comment: The plural of octopus is octopodes, so the plural of the made-up word Prius may as well be Priodes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I suspect that Toyota's advertising department just made up a word they thought sounded nice. If it were Latin and a noun/adjective, the plural would be *priora*. Since this probably is not the case, *Priuses* seems to be the only choice.

Comment: Is that an *a priori* assumption?

Comment: @Robusto: The Latin plural? Both a priori and a posteriori. There can be no other plural according to grammar, and I have seen it a lot.

Comment: @Cerberus: I guess I needed the smiley after all ...

Comment: @Robusto: No you didn't. I assumed you added that as a joke, but decided to bite, because... well, I don't know, har har.

Comment: @Cerberus: While your suspicion sounds plausible enough, I would like to imagine that there is certainly more to naming a car than just that, you know, something deeper :)

Comment: @Jimi: Hehe, well, I am the sworn enemy of the advertising industry; in that role I will say that there was probably no more to it than some brainstorming and superficial market research by people who'd never seen a decent book! <draws sword and approaches giant windmill>

Comment: @Cerberus: Where do you get that from? The standard plural would be "prii", I'm quite sure.

Comment: @Noldorin: You don't say... have you forgotten it is a word of the 4th declension?

Comment: @Cerberus: 4th declension plural would be “prius”.

Comment: @Gilles: Noldorin was joking with me so I joked back... or so I hope.

Comment: According to wiktionary, 'prius' is a Latin adverb meaning 'previously'.  Since adverbs don't have have plurals in English 'Prius' can't have a plural.

Comment: @oosterwal: In Latin, "prius" is the neuter form of the adjective "prior"; the neuter form also happens to be used as an adverb for comparatives. If we took it as an adjective, a plural form could theoretically be used.

Comment: @oosterwal: OED 1989 gives three citations for the word - two of which refer to *"**the** prius"*, and one to *"**an** absolute prius"*. They don't specify the "part of speech", but it sure looks like a noun to me.

Comment: @Cerberus: You don't explicitly address OP's corollary question *"and why?"*, but I'm guessing you'd agree with me that regardless of this rare pre-existing Latin word, Toyota's usage is effectively a neologism. The general rule is that all neologisms are *regular*, which is why the "correct" plural can only really be **Priuses**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes, there the adjective is used substantively (that is generally very common with adjectives and demonstrative pronouns in Latin and Greek).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Not regardless, but yes I agree it is a neologism and the conclusion is obvious, hehe.

Answer (score 16):

I wish people would stop referring to the latin/greek roots and words.  According to normal grammatical rules assuming the Prius is a proper noun (which it is), then you simply add an "s" but since it ends in "s" you add "es".  So it is properly Priuses.  I have a friend named Gus and an uncle named Gus as well.  When I am with both of them I am with 2 Guses.  Not Guii or Gusiay or whatever.  You cannot under any circumstances change the name of something.  If you have a Prii then you have no Priuses.

Answer (score 7):

Octopus -> Octopi

Prius -> Prii (pronounced pree-eye).

That's my story, and I'm sticking to it.  I plan on never being anywhere where more than one Prius is present.  That way, I will never have to use it in conversation.

All jokes aside, I don't think proper nouns are supposed to be subject to the rules of plurality, and Priuses would be the most common usage.

EDIT: Apparently Toyota actually had a poll about this, and the ["offical" answer](http://www.toyota.com/upcoming-vehicles/prius-family/?siteid=Media_PriusFamilyReveal_Mar_9_11_2011) from Toyota is now **prii**.  It goes along with a big ad campaign about their new Prius models.  I'm not sure how I feel about this.

Comment: Dictionaries tend not to agree on octopi.  I'll give you that.  Merriam-Webster indicates `plural oc·to·pus·es or oc·to·pi` - http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/octopus
The online oxford English dictionary counters with this:
`The standard plural in English of octopus is octopuses. However , the word octopus comes from Greek, and the Greek plural form octopodes is still occasionally used . The plural form octopi is mistakenly formed according to rules for Latin plurals, and is therefore incorrect.`  I'm with Webster on this one, but there is room for disagreement.

Comment: In all this debate we do sometimes forget that *octopus* is in fact a Latin word.

Comment: As Zoot says, "octopodes" would be the actual Greek plural for "octopus". Similarly, "antipus" would be the actual Greek singular for "antipodes." The use of these forms in English is not recommended.

Comment: Many words that come to English from Greek words ending *-ος* take the Latinate endings *-us* in the singular, and either *-i* or *-uses* (or both) in the plural. For example *discus*, *abacus*, *brontosaurus*, *platypus*, *hippopotamus*, *sarcophagus*, *hippocampus*. This is similar to the way the Greek diphthong *αι* regularly gets changed to the Latin equivalent *ae* (later *e* in AmE) (haematology/hematology) or *οι* to *oe* (or *e*) (*oestrogen* or *estrogen*).

Comment: But, as others have hinted, the *-us* in *octopus* does not in fact come from Greek *-ος*, but rather from *-ους*, via another regular change *ου* -> *u* (like the first *u* in *museum*).

Comment: Was this question about octopi or Priuses? **:^)**

Comment: My parents each have one, so I have no choice.

Answer (score 3):

Even if we assume that "Prius" is Latin, not all Latin words that end in -us are made plural by changing the -us to -i. As Cerberus notes, in Latin "prius" is the neuter form of the adjective meaning "before" -- with the masculine and feminine forms both being "prior". The plural of "prius" in Latin is "priora". (Cerberus said all this between his original post and later comment so I upvoted his answer, but perhaps this clarifies a little.)

But just because an English word looks like a Latin word doesn't make it a Latin word, especially when it's the name of a product, which would often be a made-up word.

I'm reminded of the story of the Latin professor who reported to the police that he had been mugged. "Could you identify the hoodlums?" the policeman asks. And the professor pedantically replies, "You mean 'hoodla'."

Answer (score 2):

The plural of *Prius* is *Prius cars* or more formally, *Prius automobiles*.

Marketers. Sheesh.

Comment: Those are the plurals of "Prius car" and "Prius automobile", not the plural of *Prius*.

Comment: No way :) Thanks, @Kosmonaut. @ghoppe: Well, you could say that's a great way to avoid having to pluralize *Prius* directly!

Comment: @Kosmonaut The point I am making is that this question is just a repeat of marketing drivel. (Mostly) no one is really concerned that the plural of Prius is cumbersome, any more than the plural of say, Dodge is cumbersome. You would seldom hear "he owns two Dodges" (because the word is also a verb and sounds weird) you would hear "he owns two Dodge trucks". Same goes with Prius. My sister has owned two Prius cars.

Comment: Hm.  I agree with you that some things are simply marketing drivel, but in my experience it is quite common to call vehicles *Fords*, *Jeeps*, *Saturns*, and whatnot.  The thing I am surprised about is that I've heard *Priuses* as the plural of *Prius* many times, and nothing else.  I hadn't realized people were unsure of how to pluralize it.

Comment: I think you have it exactly backwards. If Toyota marketing care about the question, they will probably assert that the plural is as you says, just as Sony marketing insist that the plural of Walkman is "Walkman personal stereos". The rest of us ignore the marketeers, and carry on saying Walkmans and Priuses (or Walkman and Prii if we feel like it)

Answer (score 2):

There is no *correct* plural for the word *Prius* at the moment. The matter is still up for debate. It is left to Toyota to determine what this should be. The company has, however, graciously opted to standardize the plural of *Prius* based on popular opinion. To contribute or make your voice heard on what you think the correct plural form should be, go cast your vote on the Toyota website [website](http://www.toyota.com/upcoming-vehicles/prius-family/?srchid=K610_p372324414). The options are: *priuses*, *prium*, *prien*, *prius* and *prii*.

Comment: No. Toyota can decide what they want it to be. The rest of the English-speaking world may or may not decide to follow them.

Comment: I disagree. OED's (1989) entry *prius - that which takes precedence; the superior, first, chief* doesn't give a plural. Presumably because they thought the plural would never be relevant to anything. Imho, Toyota's use is effectively a neologism - it's extremely rare for neologisms to be irregular, so on any rational basis the "correct" plural should **Priuses**. And as Colin implies, it probably wouldn't make much difference if Toyota chose to push for something different (but I can't imagine they would).

Answer (score 2):

*Prius* is a loanword from the Japanese *puriusu* ([プリウス](http://jisho.org/words?jap=puriusu&eng=&dict=edict)), an abbreviation of *puritii usuita*.  *puritii* ([プリティー](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%83%BC&eng=&dict=edict)) is, in turn, a loanword from English: *pretty*.  *usuita* ([薄板](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E3%81%86%E3%81%99%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F&eng=&dict=edict)) means laminate or veneer.

When we pluralize loanwords in English, we can choose to either follow the pattern of the original language or simply follow the English rules.  In general, Japanese lacks plural forms (or, to put it another way, every noun is a mass noun) which is why, for instance, *samurai* is often pluralized as just *samurai*.

So you can choose:

- *A greenwash* (the [collective noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_collective_nouns))
- *Prius* (follow the Japanese pattern)
- *Priuses* (follow the English pattern)
- Whatever dumb form Toyota's marketing department comes up with (not recommended)

Comment: Are options (1) and (4) distinct, then? Who came up with *a greenwash of Priuses*? :)

Comment: @Quuxplusone *greenwash*?  Well, I can't say for sure.  A lot of these things are just made up, y'know.

Answer (score 1):

No plural is needed. Attributive modifiers are always used in the singular and trademarks are attributive modifiers.

Correct: Hand me the *Yugoslavia* report.
Correct: Hand me the *Yugoslavia* reports.
Incorrect: Hand me the *Yugoslavias* report.
Incorrect: Hand me the *Yugoslavias* reports.

Just as *Yugoslavia* identifies the country a report is attributed to, *Prius* identifies the named line of vehicles a car is attributed to. There is only, and can ever be, one such named line.

I suppose one could imagine a case where there were two different lines of cars both called *Prius*. For example, one can talk about the "Koreas" to mean both North and South Korea. But that would be the only case where one would need a plural of Prius.

Incorrect: I could have had two V8's.
Correct: I could have had two V8 brand vegetable juice beverages.
Correct: Both my wife and I have Prius cars.
Correct: My car is a Prius, and so is my wife's.
Ambiguous: I'm glad I'm a man, and so is my wife.

You can read these, and many other fine rules that no sane person follows, in [INTA's trademark usage guide](http://www.inta.org/Media/Documents/2012_TMUseMediaInternetPublishing.pdf).

Comment: So it's wrong to say, "There are two Fords in the parking lot" or "I drank two Cokes yesterday"? I don't know what rule that breaks, or why we should obey such a rule.

Comment: @Jay See my link which answers (or at least tries to answer) both of those questions.

Answer (score -1):

Since we're all geeks on this here intermanet-thingy, I propose we use geek-speak and declare the plural of *Prius* is *Priussen* (like the plural of VAX is VAXXEN.)

Comment: No, the plural of *Vax* - in certain circles - is [Vaxen](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/V/VAX.html) (single "x").

Comment: We call them *vaxen* and *boxen* to match the plural of *ox*.  By that line of reasoning, it should be *prii*.  Yuck!

Comment: Surely if we're trying to match the plural of *ox*, the best answer is *Proxen*. ;)