# Two octopi? What's the proper plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, latin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Octopuses, octopi, or octo?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270/octopuses-octopi-or-octo)

What is the "proper" plural of "octopus"?  A web search turns up three candidates, but is there a "right" answer?

Comment: I ended up having a discussion about this in the "Plural for Prius" question, as I jokingly suggested that "Prius" be treated like "Octopus"
http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8554/what-is-the-plural-of-prius/8580#8580

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**There is no one "right" answer per se.**  [According to Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/octopus), both *octopuses* and *octopi* are acceptable plurals.

The reason for the *octopi* plural is because some people mistakenly associate *octopus* with Latin words like *syllabus* and *alumnus*.  Since these words take an *-i* plural in the original Latin, and since Latin has enjoyed such a high status in the minds of English speakers for such a long time, people have attempted to maintain or reintroduce the Latin plural form for such words.

However, the word *octopus* is actually of Greek origin.  The plural of *octopus* in Greek is, in fact, *octopodes*.

Now, I am not advocating using the form *octopodes* as the plural for this word. English borrows many nouns from other languages (Japanese, Russian, Arabic, and so on) and only rarely ever uses the morphological system of that language to create plural forms.  (Even many borrowed Latin *-us* words do not ever take the *-i* plural suffix, like *circus*.)

**So, you have three choices:**

1. Use *octopuses* and pluralize it like any other average English word.
2. Use *octopi* and force an etymologically inappropriate Latin suffix onto an innocent Greek word.
3. Use *octopodes* and probably have to explain each time that "technically" this is the correct plural in Greek (which might be a hit at parties?).

As I said, there is no one right answer.  Good luck to you!

Comment: *octopuses* is probably the best option. *octopi* invites correction from pedants (including me!), and *octopodes* invites you to join the pedants.

Comment: Agreed. This is probably the best strategy: say *octopuses*, and just save *octopodes* in case an uninformed pedant comes along who suggests it is *octopi*. Then you nail them.

Comment: +1 For *octopuses* and a clear overview of the disadvantages of each option. Basically they all suck.

Comment: I find the best treatment of how *octopus* can and cannot be legitimately inflected as a Latin word is at http://diesgaudii.genvid.com/latin/plural/index.html. To say *syllabus* is Latin and *octopus* is not is an oversimplification... both can be said to derive from Greek via Latin.

Comment: Pronunciation, please - OCT-o-podes or OCT-oppo-DEES?

Comment: @peterG: oc.TO.po.des. Four syllables, stress on the second syllable.

Answer (score 2):

*Octopuses* is the normal English plural.

*Octopi* is common, but incorrect -- it might be correct if *octopus* were of Latin derivation, but it is actually from the Greek. Like other abominations such as *irregardless*, though, it is recorded as a common usage in dictionaries (which are descriptive, not prescriptive).

The technically correct, but vanishingly rare, plural is *octopodes*.

Answer (score 1):

Both *octopuses* and *octopi* are accepted alternatives.  *Octopuses* is probably more common and gaining ground since it follows the most common rule for plurals.  (The form *octopi* is the plural form from Latin; the biological genus name *Octopus* is from Latin, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

The most common plural for *octopus* is *octopuses*. People with a background in Greek or who want to sound pedantic may use *octopodes* although it is rarely used. Some people (and dictionaries) also use *octopi* thinking it is how Latin would do the plural for *octopus*, but *octopus* actually comes from Greek not Latin. I don't know if there is a "right" answer since what is right in language comes from how words are used over time. Here is how I would describe the plurals:

**octopuses** - sounds the least strange and most commonly used

**octopodes** - technically correct based on etymology, but rare and people may assume you are incorrect

**octopi** - technically incorrect, but not uncommon